# Buffering Android AudioRecord read with System.arraycopy

Tags: android, performance, audio, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

**Description:**
I'm doing some realtime-ish audio processing on Android.  Mic audio is 1.) immediately looped back to playback device, and 2.) accumulated in a buffer that is periodically sent to server for processing.

**Issue:**
Step 1 works great.  Step 2 works alright, but the audio is noticeably noisier/glitchier than when listening to the looped-back audio from Step 1.

**Possible Clues:**

1. The effect rapidly worsens as fastBufferSize increases beyond AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize, but the looped-back audio sounds fine (other than slight increase in delay).  Specifically, it sounds like the audio samples are not shifted correctly in time, or perhaps incompletely copied.  Possible description: a smooth ramp audio signal ends up sounding like a warbly ramp.
2. Adjusting recordBufferSize or slowBufferSize seem to minimally impact audio quality.
3. I'm reasonably confident that the data isn't being corrupted when being sent server-side and also that the server is faithfully reconstructing the audio.
4. I am using PCM16 audio format, but observe similar behavior when trying PCM8.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Relevant code snippets below.

**Current Implementation:**
AudioRecord and AudioTrack are initialized:

```
recordBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateHz, CHANNELS, AUDIO_FORMAT);

// ORIGINALLY, fastBufferSize was going to be set like this, but also results in glitchy audio, happy spot seems to be right around minBufferSize
// String outFramesPerBuf = manager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
// fastBufferSize = Integer.parseInt(outFramesPerBuf);
// if (fastBufferSize == 0) fastBufferSize = 256; // Use default

fastBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateHz, CHANNELS, AUDIO_FORMAT);

// Build mic, NOTE: recordBufferSize should be larger than fastBufferSize
recorder = new AudioRecord.Builder()
    .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION)
    .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
        .setEncoding(AUDIO_FORMAT)
        .setSampleRate(sampleRateHz)
        .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
        .build())
    .setBufferSizeInBytes(recordBufferSize)
    .build();

// Build player
player = new AudioTrack.Builder()
    .setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
        .build())
    .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
        .setEncoding(AUDIO_FORMAT)
        .setSampleRate(sampleRateHz)
        .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO)
        .build())
    .setBufferSizeInBytes(fastBufferSize)
    .build();
```

A producer thread handles AudioRecord.read, AudioTrack.write, and transfers data from the fastAudioBuffer to a volatile slowAudioBuffer:

```
read = recorder.read(fastAudioBuffer, 0, fastBufferSize);

if (read > 0) {
    synchronized (slowAudioBuffer) {
        // Shift slowAudioBuffer
        System.arraycopy(slowAudioBuffer, 0, slowAudioBuffer, read, slowBufferSize - read);

        // Copy new audio into slowAudioBuffer
        System.arraycopy(fastAudioBuffer, 0, slowAudioBuffer, 0, read);
        }

        if (currentState == UserState.PASSTHROUGH) {
            player.write(slowAudioBuffer, 0, read, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
        }
}
```

A consumer thread copies the volatile slowAudioBuffer to sampleAudioBuffer and sends it for processing:

```
synchronized (slowAudioBuffer)
{
    // Copy slowAudioBuffer into sampleAudioBuffer
    System.arraycopy(slowAudioBuffer, 0, sampleAudioBuffer, 0, sampleBufferSize);
}

// Process at remote server
processAudioRemote(sampleAudioBuffer);
```